# Count same values in 1 record

Tags: salesforce, apex

Googled a lot, but can't find good directions or code for my problem...

**The issue:**

In Salesforce Apex i want to count the same values in 1 record inside an object.

*Example record*

**ID | Columname1 | Columname2 | Columname3 | Columnname4**

01 | ValueWrong | ValueisGood | ValueWrong | ValueNormal

If the record has more then 1 'ValueWrong' values, then it must be marked as incomplete. That's why i need to count (same) values inside a record, to make that formula.

Hope you can help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For this solution, I am assuming the column names are not actually name ending on consecutive numbers and they are named arbitrarily.

Since you're using Apex, one option you have is using an auxiliary variable that counts the amount of occurences of `ValueWrong`.
Use a trigger on `insert` and `update` (before or after depending on your use case) that determines the amount of occurences of `ValueWrong` there.

```
Number count = record.Columnname1 == 'ValueWrong' ? 1 : 0;;
count += record.Columnname2 == 'ValueWrong' ? 1 : 0;
count += record.Columnname3 == 'ValueWrong' ? 1 : 0;
count += record.Columnname4 == 'ValueWrong' ? 1 : 0;

if (count > 1) {
  // Mark as incomplete
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to check all fields and their names are unknown. Use something like this as seen in [another answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21213/apex-dynamically-get-fields-for-an-sobject-no-hardcoding/21242):

```
SObjectType type = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('YourObject');
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldsMap = type.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
```

Which you can use to iterate all fields dynamically.